# Eliminate errors in internal linking

Tags: linking

Situation:

based on url mywebsite.com/products/company/product-name/ I discovered that I can create a url mywebsite.com/products/WHATEVER/product-name/ and it will still work and display that page, which, unlike 404, is worse.

Need:
elimination of such a technical possibility (eliminating such links in internal linking)

Thanks in advantage

Comment: Can you rephrase what you mean by "always bring a double"? I don't understand what's meant

Comment: It means that I can access to website with any words/signs between /products/ and /product-name/ without particular word I want (in this case company). I dont want it to happen. I want to show 404 to all that kind of actions because it can cause to index some random links is serp while bad bots start crwaling and make traffic.

Comment: if you're worried about search engines that's not an issue as long as you have the canonical tag set in the header, the search engine will recognise the correct URL regardless of how it gets there if it's present. WP automatically does this for you normally

Comment: see https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en and https://www.canonicaltag.com/,  you can have 1000 URLs for your page, as long as they all have the same canonical tag, search engines will only index that canonical URL in the tag

Comment: So there is no other SEO issue that this situation can cause? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: It's not an SEO concern if you have the canonical URL tags set up. By default WP even redirects to the canonical URL, e.g. https://tomjn.com/bfkhjsbfkf/escaping/ redirects to https://tomjn.com/escaping/ on my own site, adding an additional directive for search engines for the pages true location. If it was an issue, it would show up in Google Search Console